# How to get the "Group" name from a Artboard loop in Adobe XD

Tags: plugins, adobe-xd

I was wondering if someone could help me get the Group **name / title** for a Adobe XD plugin I am working on.

I have tried doing **element.Group** but it comes back as undefined. I can see it in the loop if I **console.log(element)** but can't target the name.

If anyone can help that would be great!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I Figured it out.

It was just **element.name**, simple :)

Closing question down.